# RestTemplate Swagger Not enough variable values available to expand

Tags: java, rest, swagger, resttemplate

My method throws an exception:

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/orders/{email}")
    private List<Order> ordersByEmail(@PathVariable String email) {
        List<Order> list = restTemplate.exchange(
                "http://localhost:8082/api/v1/orders/email/{email}",
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new HttpEntity<>(email),
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Order>>() {
                }).getBody();
       }
```

the request url method:

```
@ApiOperation("Find orders by email")
    @GetMapping(value = "/email/{email}")
    public List<Order> findOrdersByEmail(@PathVariable String email) {
        return orderService.findByEmail(email);
    }
```

curl:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8084/api/v1/processor/orders/{email}?email=string" -H "accept: */*"
```

request url:

```
http://localhost:8084/api/v1/processor/orders/{email}?email=string
```

swagger response:

```
Error:
   Response body
            Download
            {
                 "timestamp": "2019-01-04T00:27:34.059+0000",
                 "status": 500,
                 "error": "Internal Server Error",
                 "message": "Not enough variable values available to expand 'email'",
                 "path": "/api/v1/processor/orders/%7Bemail%7D" 
            } 
   Response headers
            connection: close
            content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
            date: Fri, 04 Jan 2019 00:27:34 GMT
            transfer-encoding: chunked
```

Comment: sry, instead of @ RequestParam i putted @ PathVariable and also changed my request url in ordersByEmail method, but the problem is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is with {email}.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/orders/{email}")
private List<Order> ordersByEmail(@PathVariable String email) {
```

By specifying {email} and PathVariable, it means that your controller will take the variable after /orders/ and assign it to email.

Try `http://localhost:8084/api/v1/processor/orders/string` and `curl -X GET "http://localhost:8084/api/v1/processor/orders/string" -H "accept: /"` instead. you do not need to explicitly enter {email} in your url